# "Too few parameters" trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database in R

Tags: mysql, r, ms-access, odbc, rodbc

I'm using RODBC to connect to a microsoft access database. Some queries work fine, but on one I keep getting the errors:

```
07002 -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT baseunit FROM archiverapp_common_units WHERE unitname = "ng/ml"'
```

I am using the 'sqlQuery' function to make the query. The SELECT statement given in the error is what I intend it to be and works when I copy-paste directly into Access. From what I've gathered looking at similar posts this frequently results from misspelling a column or table name, but everything seems correct here.

Comment: Might be a locale/encoding issue with your `ng/ml` have you tried typing in this query at the command line?

Comment: You got me fooling around with the command line and I figured out it apparently doesn't like you using double quotes, single ones work fine.

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out - apparently the answer was to use single quotes instead of double quotes in the WHERE clause. Changing the query string in my R code from this

```
'SELECT baseunit FROM archiverapp_common_units WHERE unitname = "ng/ml"'
```

to this

```
"SELECT baseunit FROM archiverapp_common_units WHERE unitname = 'ng/ml'"
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Did you have to escape them? Posting your final command would be heplful

Comment: Nope, no escaping if you use double quotes around the string in R. Although escaping doesn't hurt.

Comment: Had the same issue. First I thought it was related to the UNION type of my query. After a few attempts narrowed it down to the used double quotes by calling field `Format(DtTm, "Short Date") as Dt, `. Replaced with single quotes; and, query call from `RODBC::sqlQuery()` in `R` works fine. Thanks!